# LaTeX Error: Unicode character − (U+2212) When Trying to Insert Phi, Rho, etc. within Sentence

Tags: symbols, unicode

[image]

I have the highlighted sentence showing up in Overleaf using LaTex using the following text/code:

```
where $\Phi_2$ corresponds to CDF of the bivariate normal 
distribution with expectation zero, unit variances, and 
correlation coefficient $\rho$$\in$[−1,1] [18]
```

However, I am getting the error:

> LaTeX Error: Unicode character − (U+2212)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  How do I fix the error?

Comment: Note that if we are using Unicode engine with Unicode fonts then this problem doesn't exists. The minus character U+2212 is present in the Unicode math fonts and in the text fonts too. On the other hand, the syntax $\rho$$\in$[−1,1] is completely wrong. The \in has no spaces around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unicode 2212 is the minus sign - notice that `[-1,1]` became `[1,1]` in the output.  Delete and retype that character.  Also, `$\rho$$\in$[−1,1]` should be `$\rho\in[-1,1]$`.  And if `[18]` is a reference, you should be using a better referencing system.